# Creating a single graph using two queries with differing dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two different queries with the following results and dates. I would now like to create a query that will allow me to create 1 single graph:

[image: current output: two queries]

Desired query output:

[image: desired query output]

The blank cells could be 0 if needed.

[image: desired graph]

Graph would look similar to the one above, but this example is missing Aug 31st, which is what I am trying to solve.

Comment: what kind of graph? share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 let me know if my updated question with an example of the graph is sufficient. else i will see if i can share the sheet (i am not the owner)

Answer (score 0):

the line chart is based on series so you need to reorganize your data like this:

```
=QUERY({QUERY(A2:B10, "select A,B,'1'", );
        QUERY(C2:D10, "select C,D,'2'", )}, 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3", )
```

[image]

and then get a line chart:

[image]

[image]

Comment: interesting, i think i'll have to throw in the {QUERY(A2:B10, "select A,B,'1'", );
        QUERY(C2:D10, "select C,D,'2'", )} part into sheets to see exactly what is going on there and hopefully understand it better. thanks, i'll comment any questions i may have when i wake up